# Are there any game mechanics that affect gem drop quality?

Tags: diablo-iii

Does having greater magic find or gold find affect the quality of the gems dropped? If I have a decent amount of magic find and a monster was going to drop a Chipped Ruby, is it possible for the magic find to update it to a Flawed? Or it is based solely on the difficulty level you are on and the static drop rates of gems?

Comment: Maybe gold find affects it. Why do not enlarge a bit the scope of the question to avoid redoing another similar?

Comment: @Drake You think maybe increasing gold find might increase your odds? Is that what you're saying?

Comment: I don't know but I am interested in it. so instead of doing 2 separate questions one with magic find and one with gold find maybe you can enlarge the scope of your to include it.

Comment: @Drake Changed the title a bit to add in your thoughts.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How/where can I farm gems?](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/67317/how-where-can-i-farm-gems)

Answer (score 2):

Gems are not magic items (their names are in white, not blue/gold/green), so increased chance to find magic items does not affect them.

In Diablo 2, increased MF did not affect gem drops, and I haven't heard anything about this changing in D3.

Answer (score 1):

## No.

As you can see in [**What does increased magic find do?**](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/66176/what-does-increased-magic-find-do) and the [recap](http://www.diablofans.com/topic/41361-recap-diablo-iii-magic-find/)

> Magic Find has always been one of the most popular item attributes in
> Diablo. Magic find helps increase the probability that a higher
> quality item will drop from monsters.

### Conclusion

This need more tests, but you can follow the main idea. Magic find does **not** increase the drop chance for gems.

Comment: The first source seems to give the opposite conclusion, and the second source has nothing to do with gems (and is most likely a case of RNG and the poster seeing what he wants to see based on a random idea).

Comment: @dpatchery sorry if I didn't express myself as I wished. I'll edit

Comment: The tests cited here make [my pseudo-scientific gem survey](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/68931/3129) look like the sort of thing that would pass peer review for a major journal. They're worse than anecdotal as evidence of anything.

Comment: @LessPop_MoreFizz removing the unnecessary information then